# Getting started with interior point methods

Tags: optimization, references

I want to learn about the interior point methods. I started with the wiki http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interior_point_method. However, I am having difficulty grasping the idea behind it. Can anyone provide me good links, video tutorials or pointers that can help me understand it?

Answer (score 2):

Stephen Boyd's lecture notes on convex optimization are a great starting point:

(Lecture 12 here: http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/lectures.html)

Combine that with the textbook (free available here: http://www.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/) and the corresponding video lectures (http://www.stanford.edu/class/ee364a/videos.html) and you should be good to go.